# Using FOR ALL ENTRIES for validation multiple lines

Tags: validation, abap

I have a question concerning the **For all Entries** statement in ABAP.
I know that it functions like a **Select Distinct** and deletes duplicate entries.

In my case, I want to write a validation for table inputs. As you can enter more than one line, I have to check every single one of them.
*Loop with Select* is not an Option. The alternative is **For all Entries**. Sadly if f.e. the same company code needs to be validated, FoE just gives back one entry. So I have no chance to identify where the error was (if there is one).

Here is the Code for the validation:

```
  LOOP AT extract.
    IF <xact> NE empty.
      READ TABLE total WITH KEY <vim_xextract_key>.
      IF sy-subcs EQ 0.
        MOVE <vim_total_struc> TO ls_y.
        APPEND ls_y TO lt_y.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.


  SELECT bukrs
  FROM t001
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_y 
  WHERE bukrs = @lt_y-bukrs
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_check_bukrs).

IF lt_check_bukrs IS INITIAL.
    MESSAGE 'Error in company code' TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
    vim_abort_saving = abap_true.
  ENDIF.
```

Maybe one of you has an approach or an idea.
Thank you for all answers!

Comment: It is not clear, what you want to check, please provide code.

Comment: If added the code to the question :)

Comment: OK, but I still don't get what is the problem. T001 contains every company code only once (as it is the only key field of the table (apart MANDT)), so even if the lt_y table has the same company code several times, it will be only selected once.

Comment: The problem is that I need the output for every row so that I can check which entry in the table (lt_y), had no result.

Comment: you make a LOOP on lt_y and READ TABLE T001 (=>lt_check_bukrs) and if the sy.subrc is 0 the company code is valid, otherwise not valid. It does not matter how many lines you have in lt_y with the same company code.

Comment: On the other hand, if it is a maintenance view for a customer table (looks like it is), just create "foreign key" for the company code field in the table in SE11 (mark field, click "Foreign key" and I guess it will automatically suggest table T001, if the field is called BUKRS), and most of your problems are solved.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's currently impossible to compile it and run it, and so not possible to post a verified answer.

Comment: to flag every erroneous BUKRS you should have in your `extract` structure not only company code but combination with another field which constructs the key, otherwise you will not be able to distinguish which line of extract caused the validation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the company code table should not be too long (in any sanely configured system), I would load it into the application server and do the comparison on the ABAP layer instead of the database layer.

```
SELECT bukrs
  FROM t001
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_all_bukrs).

LOOP AT lt_check_bukrs REFERENCE INTO DATA #(lr_check_bukrs).
  IF NOT line_exists( lt_all_bukrs[ lr_check_burks->bukrs ] )
    MESSAGE |Document { lv_check_bukrs->belnr } has invalid company code { lr_check_burks->bukrs }| TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  ENDIF.
ENLOOP.
```

---

In a different case where this is not viable because the table you want to compare with is so large it would cause a `TSV_TNEW_PAGE_ALLOC_FAILED`, then I would go back to where you acquired the original data and perform an OUTER JOIN with the comparison table:

```
SELECT bkpf~opbel,
       bkpf~bukrs
   FROM bseg
   LEFT OUTER JOIN t001 ON bkpf-burks = t001~bukrs
   INTO TABLE 
   WHERE t001~bukrs IS NULL.
```

The result table should be all financial document numbers with invalid company codes.

---

Should this **also** be impossible because the source data doesn't come from the database (manual entry, read from a file, received from a webservice, whatever...) then the last option would be to pass that data to an ABAP-Managed Database Procedure. Because SQLScript can do JOINs between database tables and tables in memory. But that does require that you are using a SAP HANA database.